# Python mangles struct.pack strings written to disk

Tags: python, bit-packing

I'm working on an application writing binary data (ints, doubles, raw bytes) to a file.

Problem is, that the data is not actually written to the file the way I expect it to be:

```
>>> import struct
>>> import io
>>> out = io.open("123.bin", "wb+")
>>> format = "!i"
>>> data = struct.pack(format, 1)
>>> out.write(data)
4L
>>> data
'\x00\x00\x00\x01'
>>> out.close()
>>> infile = io.open("123.bin", "rb")
>>> instr = infile.read()
>>> instr
'\x00\x00\x00\x01'
>>> struct.unpack("!I", instr)
(1,)
```

So everything looks like it's working just fine. But upon closer examination, the `123.bin` file has following contents:

```
$ hexdump 123.bin 
0000000 0000 0100                              
0000004
```

So it looks like the bytes were swapped by `io.write()`!

The python documentation says, that `io.write()` accepts "given bytes or bytearray object", problem is, that `struct.pack` does return an `str`:

```
>>> type(struct.pack(format, 1))
<type 'str'>
```

So, what am I doing wrong? How do I convert `str` to `bytes` without any charset translation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is an oddity of `hexdump(1)`. Using `xxd(1)`, I get...

```
$ xxd 123.bin
0000000: 0000 0001                                ....
```

...which looks correct.

Looks like you have to use the `-C` option to get `hexdump(1)` to output in a sane format...

```
$ hexdump -C 123.bin
00000000  00 00 00 01                                       |....|
00000004
```

...or call it as `hd` instead.

Comment: `hexdump -C` returns `00000000  00 00 00 01                                       |....|`, so yeah, it just looks like the default mode of `hexdump` is "broken".

Answer (score 1):

The problem here isn't with python, but with hexdump. It's treating the data in the file as 16 bit little endian values. What you need to do is tell hexdump to treat the data as 8 bit values. Without looking it up, I think it's the '-c' option.

Answer (score 1):

The default output format of `hexdump` is the same as using the `-x` option, that is, according to the man page:

```
 -x      Two-byte hexadecimal display.  Display the input offset in hexadecimal,
         followed by eight, space separated, four column, zero-filled, two-byte
         quantities of input data, in hexadecimal, per line.
```

And the endianness used by `hexdump` is the architecture endianness (here likely little-endian), while you asked python to store the value in network order (big-endian).

So, the value is correctly stored, but incorrectly interpreted by `hexdump`. You can either use the `-C` option or `xxd` instead of `hexdump`.

```
$ hexdump 123.bin
0000000 0000 0100                              
0000004
$ hexdump -C 123.bin
00000000  00 00 00 01                                       |....|
00000004
```